# Modify a chained list in another function

Tags: c

I have encoded several files, which contain several functions and a structure (in my my.h). I'd like to change this structure in a function but I can't...

My my.h who's defined my structure:

```
typedef struct PrintElement
{
    char * val;
    struct PrintElement *next;
} PrintElement, *Print;
```

My main function who I initialize my structure (`new_list()` only return `NULL`):

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    Print print = new_list();
    list_a = reorder(&print);
    print_print(print);
    return 0;
}
```

My `print_print()` function only print my chained list

My function who I pass my structure address:

```
void reorder(Print * print)
{
    node(print);
}
```

My `node()` function who I finally try to modify my list:

```
void node(Print * print)
{
    print = push_list(print, "sa");
}
```

I don't understand why when I print the list in my main file, the list is empty...

Comment: You did not show the `node()` function.

Comment: That's the last function I've showed @vmt

Comment: You're not showing your `List` struct. Please _edit_ your question and add it. Also you're passing the _entire_ struct by _value_. Although that's legit it's usually better to pass a _pointer_ instead (e.g.) `List *list` as the arg

Comment: Well, it's still not complete code for a repro, and e.g. your `reorder()` function doesn't actually return a value.

Comment: Note: Reassigning a local variable, which is what an argument is, has no effect on the caller.

Comment: @vmt because I only wrote impacted things in the function and not this entire.

Comment: @CraigEstey the List structure is not the subject

Comment: @tadman so yes, I reassign a local variable but how can I directly modify the structure

Comment: Is the idea here that you want to chain that on the front? If so, it's pretty straight-forward. Allocate a new node, link in the existing chain at the end, and return a pointer to the new head. The caller's responsible for picking this up and reassigning.

Comment: I would like to directly modify the original structure who created on the main function

Comment: What do you mean by "the original structure". You said `new_list()` returns NULL?

Comment: You can declare it as `void shift(Print** head, char* data)` using a pointer-pointer to allow manipulation of that argument, or just do `Print* shift(Print* head, char* data)` to return the new head.

Comment: Yes, I primary assign this structure to NULL in the main function, and secondary in the node function I push elements to this structure. Then, I print this same structure in the main file. So I notice than when I pass this structure to the node function, I only modify a local structure and not the original. That my problem

Comment: So I don't understand what do you want to expain @tadman I'm going to do some research of my own on this

Comment: You will want to review: [Is it a good idea to **typedef** pointers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers). To print your list, all you need is `void prn (struct PrintElement *list) { while (list) { puts (list->val); list = list->next; }` Also, once you list is populated, it doesn't matter whether nodes were added to it by *forward-chaining* or *insert-at-end*. The only difference will be the list filled by chaining will be in reverse order to the order the nodes were added.

Comment: Just demonstrating two common approaches to doing list insertion: Indirection or explicit return of new head.